# Can't get 200 OK when checking URL?

Tags: command-line, curl, http

I was trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.shellhacks.com/check-website-availability-linux-command-line/

When using the `curl -Is http://www.shellhacks.com | head -1`command, I am unable to get `200 OK` for any website at all. It is either `302 Moved Temporarily`, `301 Moved Permanently` or `307 Temporary Redirect`. I am looking to check if a particular website can process requests.  When I read about 3xx, it says it is sort of a relocation. But then, doesn't that mean that my particular website can't process requests? It seems like the location it is relocated to would be processing my requests instead.

How should I consider the 3xx cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are able to obtain `200 OK` HTTP response, but you can't eventually see it with `head -1`. 
The crucial option is `-L`:

> ```
> -L, --location
> ```
>
> (HTTP/HTTPS)  If  the  server  reports  that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a `Location`: header and a `3XX` response code), this option will make `curl` redo the request on the new  place.  If  used together  with  `-i`, `--include` or `-I`, `--head`, headers from all requested pages will be shown.

---

```
$ curl -LIs http://www.shellhacks.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2018 12:58:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.shellhacks.com/
X-Page-Speed: on
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2018 12:58:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Link: <https://www.shellhacks.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Set-Cookie: qtrans_front_language=en; expires=Wed, 13-Mar-2019 12:58:31 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/
X-Page-Speed: on
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware it would try to connect to the new address later.